# На каких данных обучать нейронные сети по предсказанию гистограмм?

Tags: нейронные-сети, машинное-обучение, генетический-алгоритм, гистограммы

Есть некоторая гистограмма.
Хочу обучить нейронную сеть предугадывать, уйдет ли эта гистограмма сильно положительном или отрицательном направлении (в момент, когда столбцы гистограммы близки к 0 или меняют знак)

В нейронках опыта не так много, поэтому что-то мог делать не правильно.

Примеры гистограммы:

[image: Пример гистограммы 1]
[image: Пример гистограммы 2]

Как видно, они относительно плавные.

У меня есть возможность обучить нейронку обычным обратным распространением ошибки, а так же генетическим алгоритмом, примерно как обучают [тут](https://github.com/ssusnic/Machine-Learning-Flappy-Bird), только еще добавил комбинирование весов (там только комбинирование сдвигов функции активации)

Я пытался обучить так:

Нейронная сеть - персептрон, по слоям - 4, 6, 3, 2

На входы:

1. Абсолютный максимум всех столбцов, взятых по модулю;
2. Максимум (по модулю) из наиболее длинной знакопостоянной последовательности столбцов;
3. Среднее столбцов (все по модулю), взятых по модулю из той же знакопостоянной последовательности;
4. Среднее из одного-двух-трех (по выбору) столбцов НЕ ПО МОДУЛЮ из того момента, в котором как раз требуется определить, уйдет ли гистограмма (ЕДИНСТВЕННОЕ ЗНАЧЕНИЕ, ИМЕЮЩЕЕ ЗНАК);

Каждый вход, плюс ко всему, делится на среднее ВСЕХ столбцов, взятых по модулю, чтобы для различных гистограмм они были примерно одного порядка.

На выходах хочу получить:

- [1,0] - Гистограмма уйдет вверх
- [0,1] - Гистограмма уйдет вниз
- [0,0] - В данный момент гистограмма не уйдет никуда

После обучения тестирую - результат с переменным успехом, даже слишком неточно

Какие могут быть способы улучшить результат?

Answer (score 1):

Если (по тексту вопроса это непонятно) по оси Х у вас время, а по оси Y - некоторые значения, полученные в соответствующие моменты времени, то ваша задача сводится к анализу временнЫх рядов - очень хорошо и подробно изученной области анализа данных.  Для таких задач использовать нейронные сети - все равно, что ездить на дачу с помощью баллистической ракеты - можно, но зачем? Есть целый ряд методов предсказания (predictive analysis) будущих значений временнЫх рядов, по отношению к которых нейронные сети никакого выигрыша не дают, но ресурсов - в частности на обучение - затрачивают несравненно больше. И ничего не надо самостоятельно изобретать.

Вот только причем тут гистограммы (под этим термином в Machine Learning и статистике понимают вполне конкретный объект) -  осталось совершенно непонятно.